# Asp.Net Mvc delete columns from database table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, controller

I am trying to delete all table data where username  = current user name. But there is some error on lambda expression and conversion."Cannot convert source type to target type. Any help?

```
public JsonResult DeleteChatMessages(int id)
        {
            string toId = Session["SessionUserName"].ToString();
            tblChat tblchats = _obj.tblChat.Where(p => p.ToId == toId);
            _obj.tblChat.Remove(tblchats);
            _obj.SaveChanges();
            return this.Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Change your line as `tblChat tblchats = _obj.tblChat.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ToId == toId)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter the "chats" you want.

```
 var tblchats = _obj.tblChat.Where(p => p.ToId == toId).ToList();
```

After iterate throught them and remove.

```
    foeach(chat in tblchats){
        _obj.tblChat.Remove(chat);
    }
    _obj.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you are expecting only one object to return from the `Where` filter.
Change your line as,because as per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) . The `Where` clause returns an `IEnumerable<TSource>`. And you are assigning that to the non IEnumerable object.

```
  tblChat tblchats = _obj.tblChat.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ToId == toId)
```

and you also might want to check for the `Null`, before removing it from the `tblChat`.

If you are expecting more than one object to match the filter and want to remove all of them then use @tmg approach.

```
    _obj.tblChat.RemoveRange(_obj.tblChat.Where(p => p.ToId == toId).ToList());
```